# Facebook API - Post does not appear in group

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post some messages to a group. It works pretty well so far, but the post are only visible to me - no one else. Does anyone have an idea what I made wrong?

```
$postdata = array (
'access_token'  =>  $user_token, // taken from the "usertoken" from Access Token Tool
'from'      =>  '100000xxxxxxxx', // my (users) ID
'message'   =>  'message',
'link'      =>  'http://www.example.com',
'name'      =>  'Name',
'caption'   =>  'Caption',
'description'   =>  'Desc',
);

$res = $facebook->api("/".$gid."/feed", "POST", $postdata);
```

Well, `$res` contains the id as expected and I can see my (auto)post. Other users get a message, that a new post is in the group. If they click on the link, a message occurs that the post is deleted or is unable to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You app must be in the **development mode**, if yes then the post will be visible to other users only after you switch it to **live**. See where you can change this setting-

[image]

Comment: I'm such a f**l. That was the solution of my problem. I knew that but I forgot. Anyway, now the app works as expected. Thanks a lot for your help! :-)